# Dashboard on WSO2DAS

Tags: wso2, wso2-das

I've created a gadget on WSO2DAS, a graph of which can be seen independently. But When I'm trying to insert it into the dashboard I'm unable to see it. [You can see the dashboard in the image but inserted gadget is not visible. Only setting and zoom in icons of it are visible.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WvmYP.png)

Answer (score 0):

Edit the following file:

```
(DAS_FOLDER)/repository/deployment/server/jaggeryapps/portal/extensions/components/gadget/index.js
```

Replace the resolveGadgetURL function with the code below:

```
  var resolveGadgetURL = function (uri) {
  uri = resolveURI(uri);
  if (uri.match(/^https?:\/\//i))
  { return uri; }
  uri = uri.replace(/^(..\/)*/i, '');
  if (window.location.protocol === 'https:')
  { return 'https://localhost:' + server.httpsPort + context + '/' + uri; }
  return 'http://localhost:' + server.httpPort + context + '/' + uri;
  };
```